# Alternate for getProperty in JSP

Tags: jsp, javabeans

I have the following code to display welcome message to user.

```
<jsp:useBean id="obj" class="com.javatpoint.User" />
<jsp:setProperty name="obj" property="*" />

Welcome, <jsp:getProperty name="obj" property="name" />
```

Is there any other way I can represent

```
<jsp:getProperty>
```

tag?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use EL. It's supported in template text since JSP 2.0 (which exist for more than a decade already; are you sure that you're reading up-to-date and self-respected resources while learning JSP?).

```html
Welcome, ${obj.name}
```

Or, if it concerns user-controlled input and thus possibly creates a [XSS attack hole](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting), use JSTL `<c:out>`.

```html
Welcome, <c:out value="${obj.name}" />
```

*(please note that your initial `<jsp:getProperty>` approach has **no** form of XSS attack prevention)*

#### See also:

- [Our EL wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/el/info)
- [Our JSTL wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info)
- [Java EE 6 tutorial - EL](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gjddd.html)

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, the `<jsp:useBean>` itself is also considered poor practice. For more detail, head to [our servlets wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info). Ideally, your JSP pages should not have any `<jsp:xxx>` tags other than `<jsp:include>`.